# Is there a way to iterate over 2 arrays with the same index

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays ingredients and measures in my margaritas object and I'm trying to render a list of ingredients to the dom where ingredients[0] is an ingredient and measures[0] is the measure of the ingredient, and so on. I cannot figure out how to make this work and I'm wondering if maybe i need to restructure my code or if i'm making a mistake somewhere.

The code is here at: https://jsfiddle.net/morjman/m4ucy0t7/3/

When I tried to do it I created a renderIngredients function which takes 2 arrays and a parent element but I think that's wrong as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like someone else mentioned, you can use a for loop:

```
  let numIngredients = margarita.ingredients.length;
  let strIngredients = ''; 
  
  for(let i = 0; i < numIngredients; i++) {
 
    let ing =  margarita.ingredients[i] || '';
    let meas = margarita.measures[i] || '';
  
    strIngredients += '<li>' +  ing  + " " + meas + '</li>'
 }
 
  const html = `
      <div class="margarita-details">
          <h2><span>${margarita.id}</span> ${margarita.name}</h2>
          <ul>${strIngredients}</ul>
          <img src="${margarita.img}" alt="${margarita.imgAlt}" />
          <p class="instructions">${margarita.instructions}</p>
          <p class="">${margarita.isAlcoholic ? "Contains Alcohol!!" : ""}</p>
        </div>
      `;
```

Answer (score 2):

why not use a regular good old array iteration?
Assuming ingredients and measures have the same array elements, you can do sth like this,

```
    for(let i = 0; i< measures.length; i++){
        //Do stuff on ingredients[i];
        //Do some other stuff with measures[i];

    }
```

Make sure they have equal number of items or else you'll end up pointing to null.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do this. But for both methods, arrays should be in equal length.

First method is the most classic way.

```
for(let i = 0; i< measures.length; i++){
    ingred = ingredients[i]
    measure = measures[i]
    // do something
}
```

The second way to do it is zip both arrays first and then iterate.

```
var zipped = ingredients.map(function(e, i) {
  return [e, measures[i]];
});
// zipped = [[ingred1,mes1],[ingred2,mes2],[ingred3,mes3],.....]
// Then iterate through the zipped array
```

And there are several other methods to zip arrays in js. refer [this](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/javascript/zip-two-arrays-in-javascript/)